Как сохранять данные в базу данных sql server из WPF проекта?
У меня не сохраняются от редактируемые данные в базу данных. У меня есть приложение по ремонту и там есть кнопка редактировать заказ, все работает и даже данные в Datagrid меняются после закрытия окошка, но сами эти данные не сохраняются в БД.
Первая часть кода это страница менеджера который меняет данные, а вторая часть кода это само коошко где и редактируется данные.
XAML ManagerPage
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TechService1WPF.Models;
using TechService1WPF.Pages;
namespace TechService1WPF.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для ManagerPage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ManagerPage : Page
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        public int user;
        public ManagerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadTable();
        }
        public void LoadTable()
        {
            var rquest = connection.technoservice1Entities.RepairRequestTable.ToList();
            TableReuqestView.ItemsSource = rquest;
        }
        private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddPage addPage = new AddPage();
            addPage.ShowDialog();
            LoadTable();
        }

        private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var repairRequestTable = (RepairRequestTable)TableReuqestView.SelectedItem;
            if (repairRequestTable != null)
            {

                Edit_Request_ManagerPAge addPage = new Edit_Request_ManagerPAge(repairRequestTable);
                addPage.ShowDialog();
                LoadTable();
            }
        }
    }
}

XAML Edit_Request_ManagerPAge
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TechService1WPF.Models;
using TechService1WPF.Pages;
namespace TechService1WPF.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Edit_Request_ManagerPAge.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Edit_Request_ManagerPAge : Window
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        public RepairRequestTable repair;
        public Edit_Request_ManagerPAge(RepairRequestTable repairRequestTable)
        {
            repair = repairRequestTable;

            InitializeComponent();

            StageComboBox.Text = repair.requestStatus;
            TechoIdComboBox.Text = repair.masterId.ToString();
            DeviceProblem.Text = repair.problemDescryption;
        }
        private void Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                repair.requestStatus = StageComboBox.Text;
                repair.masterId = Convert.ToInt32(TechoIdComboBox.Text);
                repair.problemDescryption = DeviceProblem.Text;

              
                Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while saving changes: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TechService1WPF.Models
{
    public class Connection
    {
        public Techoservice1Entities2 technoservice1Entities = new Techoservice1Entities2();
    }
}


Что за библиотеку используете для доступа к базе? Какая версия .NET и библиотеки? Что такое Connection?

использую библиотеку EntityFramework, версия 6.2.0,
добавил Connection в вопрос.

Я вижу метод LoadTable и его вызов. Но не вижу чего-то наподобие SaveTable.
